# How to get GitHub API notifications that match the notifications site

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to get the same information out of GitHub that's shown on the https://github.com/notifications page. Unfortunately, the standard [notifications API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/) doesn't really match that view.

If I get the notifications from that API (even with `participating=false`), I don't see all the items visible on the website. On the other hand, the API seems to be based on the `last_read_at` idea, and things I've seen on the website don't disappear automatically from the notifications list.

Is there a way (without scraping the website) to obtain the same `/notifications` view?

Comment: Based on the linked documentation this parameter should control whether the read threads should have to be displayed or not:
```all boolean If true, show notifications marked as read. Default: false ``` But without the your code it is a bit hard to say anything more accurate.

Comment: That parameter corresponds to the API idea of "read" unfortunately. If you click on the link itself on the website, the API doesn't know anything changed.

Answer (score 2):

So GitHub's API supports pagination for requests returning lists, so the API will return default of 30 notifications per page. What I suggest is setting the default size to 100 and then start from page 1 and call the next page till there is no results e.g. :

```
<https://api.github.com/notifications?page=1&per_page=100>; rel="next"
<https://api.github.com/notifications?page=2&per_page=100>; rel="next"
...and so on till you get an empty list then you stop
```

The rel="next" is a Link Header which is explained here: https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

Hope this helps

Comment: I checked pagination already and it doesn't really affect this issue. When items are missing there's still no "Link" header to follow. The problem goes the other way as well: I see things that are already marked as read on the web interface.